# Is it possible to execute a target based on another target result in Msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, clearcase, msbuild-4.0

I am having a task to find whether the clearcase folder has any changes or not.

```
<Target Name="CheckChanges" Returns="ItemsFromFile">

    <Exec Command="cleartool find &quot;$(FolderPath)&quot; -version &quot;{brtype($(StreamName)) &amp;&amp; created_since($(FromDate))}&quot; -print >> Changes.log" />

    <ReadLinesFromFile
             File="Changes.log" >
      <Output
          TaskParameter="Lines"
          ItemName="ItemsFromFile"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>


  </Target>

<Target Name="Build"> 

<!-- This target should be executed only when Changes.log file has contents -->

<Target>
```

If the $(FolderPath) has changes then the contents will be available in Changes.log.

What i would like to do is if the changes.log file contains some lines then run another task Build should run.

How to execute a target based on condition that the file has contents?

Answer (score 1):

> What i would like to do is if the `changes.log` file contains some lines then run another task Build should run.

The issue is that you are redirecting the result of your `cleartool find` with '`>>`'.

The first execution of the job will initialize the `Changes.log` file, and you could setup another job which test for the existence of that file (see [MSBuild conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx)) with a non-zero size in order to run. (As bit like "[verify the existence of a folder using the msbuild extension pack?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098527/6309)")

But the second execution would simply add lines (if there are changes), or keep the `Changes.log` file unchanged.
That means "`Changes.log`" would still "have content" even though the `cleartool find` didn't find any changes.

Using '`>`' instead of '`>>`' would solve that, since it would generate an empty `Changes.log` file if the `cleartool find` doesn't detect any change, or generate a non-empty file if changes are detected.